# Conditionally adding option to jQuery Ajax call

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-plugins

I have the following working Ajax call -

```
    $.ajax({
        url: ajaxUrl,
        type: sendHttpVerb,
        dataType: 'json',
        processData: false,
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        complete: function () {
            setTimeout($.unblockUI, 2000);
        },
        success: function (response, status, xml) {
            clearTimeout(delayLoadingMsg);
            $.unblockUI();
            callbackFunction(response);
        },
        error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            clearTimeout(delayLoadingMsg);
            $.unblockUI();
            dcfForm.ajaxErrorDisplay(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown)
        }
    });
```

My problem is the I conditionally want to add an option when I invoke the Ajax call.  For example, adding `data: sendRequest` before I issue the Ajax request.

My problem I cannot find an example for the syntax on how to do this without completely duplicating the entire function.

Comment: I had an answer for ya until you said "without" duplicating the entire function. That was gonna be my solution, however I agree it would be cleaner to conditionally add the option. I do apologize that that's the only way that I personally would know how to do it.

Comment: However... for your example, if you want to optionally send a parameter, how about you always send the parameter but set the value to "" with the condition before making your request.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

what about a ternary operation:

```
$.ajax({
     data: condition ? sendRequest : undefined,
     ... the rest
});
```

If that's not your taste, some people seem to forget $.ajax doesn't take a long group of paramters, but an object:

```
var ajax = {};
ajax.success = function (data) { ... };
ajax.type = 'GET';

if (myCondition) {
    ajax.data = sendRequest;
}

$.ajax(ajax);
```